# RmiRegistry não encontrado

Tags: java, rmi

Estou programando um sistema simples,utiliando RMI, para treinar programação. Porem encontrei alguns problemas ao criar o arquivo **.batch** recenbendo a mensagem no terminal do windows

> 'rmiregistry' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver este problema, caso necessário estarei enviando o codigo do programa também para ser analisado e ver se há alguma relação

---

***Classe Cliente***

```
package Client;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import Comum.IntDataHora;
import Comum.IntDataHoraImp;

public class ClienteDataHora
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            IntDataHora mensagem = (IntDataHora) Naming.lookup(IntDataHoraImp.getUri());
            System.out.println(mensagem.getDatahora());
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Erro de formação da uri");
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Erro de comunicação");
        }
        catch (NotBoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("epa! um erro!");
        }
    }
}
```

***Interface***

```
package Comum;

public interface IntDataHora
{
    public String getDatahora();
}
```

***Implementação da interface***

```
package Comum;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class IntDataHoraImp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IntDataHora
{
    private static String servidor = "localhost";
    private static int porta = 1099;
    private static String servico = "DataHora";
    private int solicitacao = 0;

    public static String getUri()
    {
        String uri = String.format("rmi//%s:%d:%s", servidor,porta,servico);
        return uri;
    }
    public IntDataHoraImp()throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatahora()
    {

        GregorianCalendar atual = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        SimpleDateFormat formatacao = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' de 'MMMMM' de 'yyyy' - 'HH':'mm'h'");
        return formatacao.format(atual.getTime());

    }

}
```

***Classe Servidor***

```
package Servidor;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import Comum.IntDataHora;
import Comum.IntDataHoraImp;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ServidorDataHora
{
    public ServidorDataHora() throws MalformedURLException
    {

        try
        {
             IntDataHora mensagem = new IntDataHoraImp();
            mensagem = new IntDataHoraImp();
            Naming.rebind(IntDataHoraImp.getUri(), (Remote) mensagem);
        } catch (RemoteException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Erro:"+ ex);
        }

    }
}
```

***Print do terminal***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem as variáveis de ambiente configuradas ? ex: [variaveis de ambiente path](https://gist.github.com/dilnei/6f3eb86cd13fb7cbae8e)

Comment: Pra ser sincero acho que eu não tenho. como posso configura-las?

Comment: esta no link acima, onde comentei.

Comment: Um `echo %PATH%` mostra o que?

Comment: @DilneiCunha obrigado mesmo, problema resolvido!

Comment: @LuizCarlosSimonard por gentileza poste a sua solução como uma resposta, talvez ajude outras pessoas!